# Uniform order-based crossover

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

I have two array A & B as follow,

```
A = [2,6,4,5,3,1]
B = [1,4,3,6,5,2]
```

From which I formed a numpy array;

```
oldArr = np.array([[2,6,4,5,3,1],[1,4,3,6,5,2]])
```

Then I must randomly pick (e.g) 3 columns, lets say;

```
idx = np.random.randint(len(oldArr[0]), size = len(oldArr[0])/2)
```

This give the index of the random numbers;

```
array([3, 4, 0])
```

and the corresponding values are;

```
[[5 3 2]
 [6 5 1]]
```

Now I want to construct a new array as such: 
I must keep those random numbers in the same position and swap 0th raw and the 1st raw in such a way that numbers should not repeat in the new array and must put the non-repeating number in the same order.

```
[2,_,_,5,3,_] # Random number positions didnt change
[1,_,_,6,5,_]
```

After swapping in my case it must be like this (we can see the numbers are unique in the raws);

```
[2,1,4,5,3,6] 
[1,2,4,6,5,3]
```

I have inserted the image here to represent in a better way.
[image]

Can anyone give some clues how to obtain the new array?. Thanks!!

Comment: Why is the `4` where it is? would `[2,4,1,5,3,6] [1,4,2,6,5,3]` also be correct?

Comment: Yes it’s correct. But I maintain the existing order when I insert the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using masking and `argsort`. It assumes that `A` and `B` are shufflings of each other.

It sorts the non pinned values in `A` in the order they occur in in `B` and vice versa.

```
import numpy as np

def reorder(a, b, idx):
    ab = np.stack([a, b])
    mask = np.ones(a.shape, bool)
    mask[idx] = False
    aidx, bidx = xidx = ab.argsort(axis=1)
    assert np.all(a[aidx] == b[bidx])
    xmask = np.empty(ab.shape, bool)
    xmask[[[0], [1]], xidx] = mask[xidx[::-1]]
    ab[::-1][np.broadcast_to(mask, ab.shape)] = ab[xmask]
    return ab

A = np.array([2,6,4,5,3,1])
B = np.array([1,4,3,6,5,2])
idx = np.array([3, 4, 0])

def make(n):
    a, b, i = (np.random.permutation(n) for _ in 'xxx')
    return a, b, i[:n//2]

def check(a, b, i):
    m = np.ones(a.shape, bool)
    m[i] = False
    result = reorder(a, b, i)
    assert np.all(np.sort(result) == np.sort(a))
    # warning: expensive!
    assert np.all(np.diff(np.where(result[1][m, None]==a)[1]) >= 0)
    assert np.all(np.diff(np.where(result[0][m, None]==b)[1]) >= 0)

for a, b, i in [(A, B, idx), make(10), make(20)]:
    m = np.zeros(a.shape, int)
    m[i] = 1
    print(np.stack([a, b, m]), '\n')
    print(reorder(a, b, i), '\n')
    check(a, b, i)
```

Sample run (prints (A; B, mask, result) for 3 examples; first example is from OP):

```
[[2 6 4 5 3 1]
 [1 4 3 6 5 2]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0]] 

[[2 1 4 5 3 6]
 [1 2 4 6 5 3]] 

[[4 2 1 6 0 7 9 3 8 5]
 [1 7 5 3 9 8 2 0 6 4]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]] 

[[1 2 7 6 0 5 9 3 8 4]
 [4 7 2 3 9 1 8 0 6 5]] 

[[ 1  4 15 18  6 19  7 13  0  8  5 17 14 12  3  9  2 11 16 10]
 [ 0  6  3  1 11 12  4  7 19 10  8 13  9 14  5 17 18 15 16  2]
 [ 1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]] 

[[ 1  4  0 18  6 11  7 13 12 19  5 17 14 10  3  8  9 15 16  2]
 [ 0  6 15  1 18 19  4  7 17 14  8 13  9 12  5  3  2 11 16 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Panzer!! This is very helpful indeed.